# How to Delete the Report Item form the BIRT Report Library

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

I have added Grid to my Report Library, I want to I delete it, is there any Delete function in eclipse, for the removal of report item from the report library?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click element in the Outline view. Delete command is present in the context menu.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You may also right mouse click on the grid in Outline view and select delete.